# How to write a regex to find HTML tags outside CDATA tags in an XML document

Tags: html, regex, xml, notepad++

I'm trying to import an ONIX (XML) file that is coming up with import errors due to HTML tags in the descriptive text. In this particular file, some of the descriptive text is enclosed in CDATA tags, but it appears that some isn't.

How can I write a regex that will find HTML tags that aren't enclosed in CDATA tags?

I'm using a VB.NET app to import the data into a SQL Server database, however at this point I'm trying to write the regex in Notepad++ just to see what's possible. I can incorporate the regex into the VB code later.

Here is an example of some XML that will import properly:

```
<OtherText>
  <TextTypeCode>01</TextTypeCode>
  <TextFormat>02</TextFormat>
  <Text><![CDATA[More than simply a series of chapters on the theology of John's Gospel, <em>Jesus Is the Christ</em> relates each of John's teachings to his declared aim, expressed in John 20: 30-31: "Jesus did many other signs before his disciples, which have not been written in this book; but these have been written that you may believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God, and that believing you may have life in his name." Indeed, each chapter in Morris's book takes up some facet or aspect of John's expressed aim.<br/><br/>For an age still asking the question "Who is Jesus?" Leon Morris argues convincingly that John's entire Gospel was written to show that the human Jesus is the Christ, or Messiah, as well as the Son of God. But it is Morris's firm conviction that John's purpose was evangelical as well as theological -- that is, John wrote his book so that readers might believe in Christ and as a result have eternal life.]]></Text>
</OtherText>
```

And here is XML that won't import properly:

```
<OtherText>
  <TextTypeCode>01</TextTypeCode>
  <TextFormat>02</TextFormat>
  <Text>More than simply a series of chapters on the theology of John's Gospel, <em>Jesus Is the Christ</em> relates each of John's teachings to his declared aim, expressed in John 20: 30-31: "Jesus did many other signs before his disciples, which have not been written in this book; but these have been written that you may believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God, and that believing you may have life in his name." Indeed, each chapter in Morris's book takes up some facet or aspect of John's expressed aim.<br/><br/>For an age still asking the question "Who is Jesus?" Leon Morris argues convincingly that John's entire Gospel was written to show that the human Jesus is the Christ, or Messiah, as well as the Son of God. But it is Morris's firm conviction that John's purpose was evangelical as well as theological -- that is, John wrote his book so that readers might believe in Christ and as a result have eternal life.</Text>
</OtherText>
```

Now,

```
<TextFormat>02</TextFormat>
```

indicates that the contents of the  tag is HTML, so I can handle that OK. The problem comes in when I have tags that aren't labelled appropriately. I need to find those so I can correct them.

Comment: Regex is probably not the right tool for this job. What you need is an XML / HTML parser that will be forgiving with the format (I'm not clear if it's non-well-formed, or just failing validation against a schema) and let you re-encode the appropriate sections.

Comment: Please post an example of a xml line that you intend to match the regex on.

Comment: Essentially that's what I'm writing. The ONIX standard allows certain fields to have HTML in them, so I'm finding those according to their attributes and inserting CDATA tags. Usually once this is done I can import the XML into a dataset and everything works well, however occasionally I come across a file that has tags that don't meet the criteria, so I get import errors.

Comment: Don't meet what criteria? Do you mean you have some existing code? Please include it in your question if so, with a clear example of where it isn't working. People are much more likely to help you improve your code than to write it for you.

Comment: I don't have any existing regex code - I'm completely new to regex, I'm working out whether I can use it to find anomalies in the XML. Anything I've tried so far hasn't done anything like what I need.

Comment: ...and yes, I could probably write something in VB.NET that doesn't use regex. I am trying to figure out whether regex is an appropriate tool for finding anomalies in the XML.

Comment: My suggestion is to abandon that line of thought, on the grounds that regex is generally poorly suited to handling the recursive structures of XML.

Comment: OK, thanks for that. From what I'd been reading about regex and it's ability to look ahead and look behind a given string, I thought it might be the solution to my problem. I'll try writing something in VB instead, unless an answer comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex can help you get somewhere:

```
<\w+>(?!<![CDATA[)
```

I ran it on the examples you provided in Sublime Text, and it only matched HTML tags that aren't followed by the CDATA stuff.

Comment: Thanks for that - I had to escape the square brackets to get it to work in Notepad++, like this:

    `<\w+>(?!<\[CDATA\[)`

It then worked as it should, however it finds all the XML tags as well! How would I modify it to find only, say <em> tags?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can just replace \w+ with em.

Comment: Thanks - should have figured that out myself!